# Docker container hosting

Tags: docker

Does someone know if there is a Docker hoster where you can just rent resources per container. All hosters I know require you to setup machines/nodes yourself first. So they are renting out machines not container resources.

I need to run 50 to 200 containers that need between 600 and 1000 MB of memory each but only a few hours per day. When I look at Amazon, Google, Digital Ocean, Linode and others, they have a weird pricing structure. The more you pay, the less you get. More expensive machines have less memory and less processors available. The smallest and cheapest machines seems to give you the most RAM and CPU per dollar.

This makes it harder to provision the machines. Using Docker Swarm does not add value as I need to have one container per machine (to get the best price/performance). So I would really like to be able to just rent per container, not per machine/node. But as far as I know nobody is offering that yet.

Comment: I would say possibly [Joyent](https://www.joyent.com/triton), but I'm basing this on the posts I read on their blog rather than any first hand experience.

Comment: I think I found exactly what I need. https://jelastic.com/cloud-hosting-platform-for-developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for a container service like you describe, but [Cycle](https://cycle.io) does exactly what you're looking for. It's super simple to use, and your containers run on bare-metal for top performance.

I'm the CTO so if you have any questions or anything let me know.